# 2D array row and column length

Tags: java, arrays

I'm studying 2D array right now, there is a part of 2D array I don't really understand. I will show my code and explain what part I don't understand.

My code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[][]array={{1,2,3},{1,2,3},{1,2,3}};
}
public static printArray(int[][]a){
    for(int row=0;row<a.length;row++){
        for(int column=0;column<a[row].length;column++)
}
```

My question is for the second method of `printArray`. In the second for loop,what does `column<a[row].length`means?

Comment: That's the length of 1 row {1,2,3}. Your example is not very nice to explain this as everything has a length of 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line gives the **size** of each row.
You know that

- a[0]={1, 2, 3}
- a[1]={1, 2, 3}
- a[2]={1, 2, 3}

---

So, a[0].length = a[1].length = a[2].length = 3. Use of this is to ensure that we dont go *Out Of Array Bounds*.

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't have 2D arrays. Java has arrays of arrays. The second loop uses column < a[row].length to make sure that you don't iterate past the length of the row-th array. You need this to handle nested arrays of varying length.

Answer (score 0):

That is the condition to check when the limit of each row is reached, in order to avoid an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 0):

A 2D array means that each element of the array is itself an array. The second loop allows you to loop through each {1,2,3} array (in your case). But to do that, you need the length of each array. That's what a[row].length provides.